# Drag and Drop images from a pop-up window or a different activity

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, popupwindow

I'm working on my Android app, in which the user supposed to drag images from some kind of an "icon keyboard" that I implement.

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to do it.
so far I implemented it as a pop-up window, but then I bumped into some problems with the Drag&Drop.

I found out there was a question asked abot this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9331124/perform-a-drag-operation-from-a-popupwindow-in-android), but there was no answer to this question.

Is it really impossible to drag from a pop-up window to the under-laying layout? if so, what is the right way to go?

Comment: What do you mean by popup? usually popups are modal so the user cannot interact with the layout under. Why not just click the image and it appears in the layout. Or have a layout slide in from the bottom screen, then you can drag and drop.

Comment: @mario - first of all, i'll clarify - I need to drag an image from the "pop-up" to the under-laying layout. And when you say "have a layout slide from bottom of screen" - using what? I found on the web one option, using a Dialog, but this is also modal, right?